# Total derivative equals partial derivative?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have $y=f(x(a, b, c), a)$,
If is do the partial derivatives for $y$ w.r.t $a$,

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$(chain rule)+$\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}$

If is do the total derivatives for $y$ w.r.t $a$,

$\frac{d y}{d a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$(chain rule)+$\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}$

Should they be the same? I use an online derivatives tool, they are the same, but I don't get it. For example, $y=f(x+a), x=sin(a+b+c)$.
[image]
[image]

Comment: They are not the same, you have done it incorrectly. The total derivative captures also the variables $b,c$

Comment: Your online calculator reports them to be the same since it is a single variable function

Comment: I changed the function

Comment: What is $f$ then? Did you mean $y=x+a$ instead of $y=f(x+a)?$ If not what are the two inputs for $f$?

Comment: It is different notation, but they are both the partial derivative with respect to $a$.  As mentioned above, you don't do the total derivative with respect to anything in particular.

Comment: f can be 1 times what input, and I don't get J126's comment

Answer (score 3):

My experience has been that no one can agree on notation for such situations. My opinion is that total derivatives should be reserved for when we are differentiating functions that can be thought of as depending on only one variable. In other words, I would say that there is no meaningful quantity $\frac{dy}{da}$. If, however, we think of $b$ and $c$ as depending on $a$, then I suppose we could write:
$$
\frac{dy}{da} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial b} \frac{db}{da} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial c} \frac{dc}{da} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}
$$
where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ is understood to be the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its second argument.

My strong recommendation would be to define more auxilliary functions so that the notation is less ambiguous unless the source you're following or the field you're working in insists on this notation.

Comment: Thank you, I know my following question could also be ambiguous, when people say gradient of a function, $f(x(a),a)$ w.r.t $a$, they write as $\frac{d f}{d a}=f_x x_a+f_a$, is this total derivative or partial?

Comment: My opinion would be that it is in fact a total derivative, and $f_a$ is the partial derivative. In this case, the distinction is easy to make clear: $f_a = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x(a), a + h) - f(x(a), a)}{h}$, while $\frac{df}{da} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x(a + h), a + h) - f(x(a), a)}{h}$.

Comment: More generically, a good rule of thumb is that a partial derivative is how some function changes as a single *argument* is changed, while a total derivative is how some function changes as a single *parameter* (which may appear in several arguments or indeed nested in several functions) is changed. But, again, no one agrees on this and a great variety of notation is used. I finally gained some clarity on these concepts when I studied smooth manifolds.

Answer (score -2):

In the partial derivative $\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}$, we measure the direct effect of $a$ on $y$, so $x(a, b, c)$ is a constant. Therefore $\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}(x(a, b, c), a) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(x(a, b, c), a)$.

In the total derivative $\frac{d y}{d a}$, we also measure the indirect effect through $x$. Therefore $\frac{d y}{d a}(x(a, b, c), a) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(x(a, b, c), a) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x(a, b, c), a) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}(a, b, c)$.

Comment: This is not correct, as far as I know and through comparison to authoritative examples

Comment: Or maybe you meant a multiplication rather than addition

Comment: Of course, this was a typo. Fixed.